# Benign cyclical dependencies

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Trying svelte for a new project I wrote a component to edit a compound object which delegates editing of individual parts to subcomponent and recreates the compound object whenever a part was changed. Of course, when the compound object is externally changed the subcomponents should be updated to the new values.

I ended up with the following:

```html
<script>  
    let item = "content";
    export let holder = { item };

    $: {
        console.log("setting item to "+holder.item);
        item = holder.item;
    }

    $: setHolder(item);

    function setHolder(i) {
        console.log("setting holder for "+i);
        holder = { item: i }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={item} />
```

The above compiles but the content cannot be edited as somehow when `item` is edited the first reactive block is executed setting the variable back to `holder.item`.

I don't understand the following:

- Why is the first reactive block executed? As `item` only appears on the left-hand-side of an assignment it is not a value it depends on.
- Why has the cyclical dependency be "hidden" from the compiler, why doesn't the following work?

```js
    $: {
        console.log("setting item to "+holder.item);
        item = holder.item;
    }

    $: {
        console.log("setting holder for "+item);
        holder = { item }
    }
```

- And why does everything work when wrapping both reactive blocks into functions?

```js
    $: setItem(holder)
    function setItem(h) {
        console.log("setting item to "+h.item);
        item = h.item;
    }

    $: setHolder(item);
    function setHolder(i) {
        console.log("setting holder for "+i);
        holder = { item: i }
    }
```

It seems odd to relying on the compiler somehow not seeing what the code is doing so I'm wondering if I'm having a completly wrong approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reactive statement will re-execute whenever *any of the variables mentioned* changes.  So your first statement will re-run when `holder` or `item` changes.

The function approach works, because all of a sudden you only mention one variables (the compiler only looks in the immediate block, not inside any functions that would be called)

I admit it's a bit confusing at first, but hope this makes it a bit clearer

Comment: While I agree with your assessment, I'm still having trouble to understand why `setItem` isn't triggered after `setHolder` updates `holder` (and it should since `holder` has been assigned an entirely new object?)
Even in the function form, we should have an illegal cyclical dependency here, or am I missing something?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this follow-up :(

Comment: @sleighty I have to say, I am not 100% sure, but it must be something with how Svelte optimizes comparing objects and primitives.  Note that if you do `bind:value?={holder.item}` it does trigger both functions.

Comment: Interesting. What does the `?` do? I've never used that syntax in Svelte haha. In my case I'm using this pattern to enhance this Tabs component so that it can be used like `<Tabs bind:selectedTab />` so I'm not running into that inner `input bind:...` bit, thankfully. (If I remember right, Rich Harris posted a link to this Tabs implementation in another SO question: https://svelte.dev/repl/8e68120858e5322272dc9136c4bb79cc?version=3.7.0)

Comment: the `?=` is a typo, lol :D